# How long takes investigation of developer account?

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm game developer and I've pushed game through appstore connect, but first time they rejected my game with message :
Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed

```
>This type of app has been identified as one that may violate one or >more of the following App Store Review Guidelines. Specifically, these >types of apps often:

>1.1.6 - Include false information, features, or misleading metadata
>2.3.0 - Undergo significant concept changes after approval
>2.3.1 - Have hidden or undocumented features, including hidden >"switches" that redirect to a gambling or lottery website
>3.1.1 - Use payment mechanisms other than in-app purchase to unlock >features or functionality in the app
>3.2.1 - Do not come from the financial institution performing the loan >services
>4.3.0 - Are a duplicate of another app or are conspicuously similar to >another app
>5.2.1 - Were not submitted by the legal entity that owns and is >responsible for offering any services provided by the app
>5.2.3 - Facilitate illegal file sharing or include the ability to >save, convert, or download media from third party sources without >explicit authorization from those sources
>5.3.4 - Do not have the necessary licensing and permissions for all >the locations where the app is used
```

After that I've re-checked all information I've provided and answered them that everything is okay with application and they changed status of my game to "In Review"
After that they responded :

>

```
    Hello,

>We are unable to continue this app’s review because your Apple >Developer Program account is currently under investigation for not >following the App Store Review Guidelines’ Developer Code of Conduct.

>Common practices that may lead to an investigation include, but are >not limited to:

>• Inaccurately describing an app or service
>• Misleading app content
>• Engaging in inauthentic ratings and reviews manipulation
>• Providing misleading customer support responses
>• Providing misleading responses in Resolution Center
>• Engaging in misleading purchasing or bait-and-switch schemes
>• Engaging in other dishonest or fraudulent activity within or outside >of the app

>During our investigation, we will not review any apps you submit. Once >we have completed our investigation, we will notify you via Resolution >Center.
```

How long it that investigation taking time?
And
Why they are rejecting my game ?

I've tried to write app store developer program contact us , but they are just answering to wait and nothing more.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to difficulties with the procedures of another website, where the difficulties are unrelated to programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: @Prime do you have any news regarding this? Is your dev. account still under the investigation?

Comment: @rootpanthera no answer yet, its already 3+ months. But my dev accounts seems valid.

Comment: What happened at the end? I got the same message today.

Comment: Was the problem solved?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1):

My Developer Account they investigating three months already :) And I think it will end with the ending of my enroll. Maybe this is their plan :)

Comment: I got the same shit last week, I'm still waiting. any update on your situation?

Comment: @asilturk Hi!
My Apple Developer account has been unlocked after 4 months of investigation (approximately)

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I waste 3 months, almost the same result :)

Answer (score 1):

Today, I got same message. I have nearly no hope. My account will be terminated I guess. I transferred my other apps just problem app was staying. Not to lose other apps when account will be terminated. I will edit when I will receive any messages

Comment: I got the same shit last week, I'm still waiting. any update on your situation?

Comment: It took 12 days but in "waiting for review" i requested expedited review with a good reason. I think it reduced waiting time. If it exceeded more than 2 days, I suggested remove update and fix what could cause this longer review. It means something going bad. Otherwise you will lose your account like me.

Comment: @asilturk I got the same problem hope nothing serious

Comment: @codaman was the problem solved?

Comment: not yet, I'm still waiting. it took 1 month almost

Comment: I've lost my two accounts. My advice is transfer another apps (not rejected). If apple choose termination of your account, you will lose other apps. And don't delete or transfer app that has problem. Wait apple to finish investigation. If you delete this app, apple will immediately terminate your account.